# What does {} mean in perl?

Tags: perl

```
my $a = {};
my $b = {$a=>''};
```

I know `{}` can be used to reference a hash key,but what does `{}` mean here?

Comment: Is that sample code something you made up, or did you find it somewhere?  Because it doesn't make much sense :)

Comment: @Flimzy,yes it's a contrived one.

Comment: Okay... setting $b = {$a => ''} doesn't make much sense (it's valid code, but not very useful), since it would set the key value to a stringified hashref.. the output of Dumper($b) would look like: **VAR1 = { 'HASH(0xb62d48)' => '' };**  Which is not very likely to be useful :)

Comment: I've seen people stringify a hash reference to create a unique ID for an inside out object back in the early 2000's.  It's been about that long since I've contemplated Inside Out objects anyway, so I don't know if it's ever used anymore.  Always seemed to me it might not be guaranteed unique anyway, if the ref ever got garbage collected it could be reissued.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

{} creates a reference to an empty anonymous hash.  Read more [here](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/pod/perlref.pod#Making_References).

Example code:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $a = {};
print "a is " . Dumper( $a );
my %b = ();
print "b is " . Dumper( \%b );
```

Outputs:

```
a is $VAR1 = {};
b is $VAR1 = {};
```

Comment: The hashref isn't anonymous, it's the hash that is. It doesn't represent a hashref, it creates one.

Comment: Well, the {} is an anonymous hash constructor. It creates a reference, whose value you can store in a variable. Still, there's no name that refers to that hash. You have to use the reference. There really isn't an anonymous reference, though.

Answer (score 10):

`{}`, in this context, is the anonymous hash constructor.

It creates a new hash, assigns the result of the expression inside the curlies to the hash, then returns a reference to that hash.

In other words,

```
{ EXPR }
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
do { my %hash = ( EXPR ); \%hash }
```

(`EXPR` can be null, nothing.)

[perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)